# that.init is not a function - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am pretty much completely new to javascript and node.js, but im working on a Connect 4 robot project. For this purpose i am trying to get a code i found on the internet to work. This is the part im having problems with:

```
Game();

function Game() {
this.rows = 6; // Height
this.columns = 7; // Width
this.status = 0; // 0: running, 1: won, 2: lost, 3: tie
this.depth = 4; // Search depth
this.score = 100000, // Win/loss score
this.round = 0; // 0: Human, 1: Computer
this.winning_array = []; // Winning (chips) array
this.iterations = 0; // Iteration count

var that = this;

that.init();
}

Game.prototype.init = function() {
// Generate 'real' board
// Create 2-dimensional array   
var game_board = new Array(that.rows);
for (var i = 0; i < game_board.length; i++) {
    game_board[i] = new Array(that.columns);

    for (var j = 0; j < game_board[i].length; j++) {
        game_board[i][j] = null;
    }


}
```

When i try to run it with node.js, i get following error:

```
that.init();
     ^

TypeError: that.init is not a function
at Game (C:\Users\*******\Desktop\New Folder\connect-four.js:21:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*******\Desktop\New Folder\connect-four.js:7:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
```

What exactly is causing this error?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Apart from missing the `new`, *never* invoke a constructor above its definition. Initialise the prototype methods first, then instantiate.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `new` to initialize an object, and only after `init` has been assigned to `Game.prototype.init`:

```
function Game() {
    (...) 
}

Game.prototype.init = function() { ... };

new Game();
```

and in the `init()` function, you have to use `this`

```
(...)
var game_board = new Array(this.rows);
(...)
   game_board[i] = new Array(this.columns);
```

Why?

- when you *call* `Game()` as your code does, `this` [by definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the global object (you can verify by setting  `global.init = ...`, the `this.init()` call then works in your code)
- adding to the prototype requires an instance of that prototype, i.e.
  `Game.prototype.init` is only inherited to instances of `Game`
- `new Game()` is what creates an instance which has
  the `init` method bound to it, so calling `that.init()` will actually work
- variables defined inside a function are only visible in the scope of the function (and functions defined within it), i.e. `that` is only visible in the `Game` function itself (which is also the constructor of `Game` objects created by the `new` operator)
- as `that` is not defined in `init` the code fails, however `this` works because it refers to the same object as in the constructor (the `Game` function)

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! Could changing "that" to "this" mean that i might be referencing the wrong object or does it make no difference?

Comment: @Kaza123 glad it helped, I added an explanation

Comment: *"...and only after `Game` has been defined"* The problem isn't that `Game` isn't defined before it's called; it was that `Game.prototype.init` wasn't defined. And *"`this` by definition is the global `Object`"*  isn't right, or is at least misleading. The global `Object` is a constructor function, and `this` does not refer to it in the OP's call. The "global object", which can be referenced via `window`, is what was set to `this`. A clearer test would be `window.init = ...`

Comment: @squint now reflects your point about `Game.prototype.init`. However, my point about `this` being the Global Object are correct, see the [ECMA specifiation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.1.1). Note the question is in relation to node.js, not a web browser.

Comment: Both Node and browsers have a global object. It just references itself via a different variable name. So instead of `window.init = ...`, it would be `global.init = ...` in Node. Same thing, different name. What you wrote was that the global `Object` would be set to `this`. `Object` is a global variable that points to a constructor function. This is not the same as referring to the *"global object"*, which is the root lexical environment. Telling the OP to add to `Object.prototype` as a test further confuses the matter.

Comment: ok thanks for pointing that out, updated. My suggested verification still worked though because `Object.prototype` applies to all objects and the main point was about why the OP code did not work. Granted, assigning to the Object.prototype is not something one should do unless for good reasons, but I never recommended this as a solution but to illustrate the point why the OP approach did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a mixture of hoisted and non-hoisted code; the `function` declaration gets hoisted, but the expression which defines `init` on that function's *prototype* doesn't, as it is an expression. This means your code is invoked in the following order;

1. Function *Game* defined
2. `Game()`
3. `Game.prototype.init = function() { /* ... */ }`

This means at the time of step 2, when you're invoking your function, *init* is not yet defined.

You need to change the order of the code so it becomes

1. Function *Game* defined
2. `Game.prototype.init = function() { /* ... */ }`
3. `new Game()`

Further, if you want the function to get it's own `this` (i.e. if it is a *Constructor*) you'll need to invoke it differently, e.g. with `new`

Answer (score -1):

Just use ES6 classes.

```
class Game {
  constructor(configuration) {
    this.rows = configuration.rows
    this.columns = configuration.columns
    this.depth = configuration.depth
    this.score = configuration.score
    this.round = configuration.round
    this.winning_array = configuration.winning_array
    iterations = 0
  }

  init() {
    // Generate 'real' board
    // Create 2-dimensional array   
    var game_board = new Array(this.rows);
    for (var i = 0; i < game_board.length; i++) {
      game_board[i] = new Array(this.columns);
      for (var j = 0; j < game_board[i].length; j++) {
        game_board[i][j] = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

// USAGE

const winning_array = []
const configuration = {
  rows: 6,
  columns: 7,
  status: 0,
  depth: 4,
  score: 100000,
  round: 0,
  winning_array: winning_array,
  iterations: 0,
}

const game = new Game(configuration)
game.init()
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I think you got `-1` because your post does not actually answer the question. ES5 constructor functions are OK, this is valid JavaScript. ES6 classes are great, but remember this is just syntactic sugar... ;)